# Adding the value of a variable to the name of an object during the creation of the object

Tags: java

I'm creating Car objects and I'm keeping count of the number of cars created with the variable 'carCounter.'  CarCounter starts at 0, and I want to name the Car objects car(carCounter) and increase the counter each time I create a car, so that the cars are named car0, car1, car2, etc...  How could I do that during the creation of the objects?

Something like Car() car(+carCounter+) = new Car();  ?

Comment: What does your `Car` look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a `static counter` variable, and each time you create an instance of your `class`, increment that variable, and set it for that instance.

```
public class YourClass {
    private static counter = 0;
    private String name;

    public YourClass() {
        name = "car" + counter;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, duh.  So simple. I don't know why I didn't think of it..  Thanks!  Just one question.  How would I instantiate an object of the class?  just type 'new Car'?

Comment: @user939287. Some things you get to know suddenly. So shouldn't be a surprise. Generally, you only learn them when you need them. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is an [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

```
Car[] cars = new Car[3];
cars[0] = new Car();
cars[1] = new Car();
cars[2] = new Car();
```

This also lets you refer to the index (what you were calling the count) via a varaible:

```
int n = 1;
Car carAtIndexN = cars[n];
```

If you're going to initialize a whole set of cars, it's better to do so in a loop:

```
int totalCarCount = 10;

Car[] cars = new Car[totalCarCount];

for (int i=0; i<totalCarCount; i++) {
  cars[i] = new Car();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Class Car {
    public static int counter= 0;
    String name="";
    public Car() {
       counter++;
       name= "car"+ counter;
    };
}
```

that is all for Car class.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain thread safety, I would recommend using a `static AtomicLong` variable for the task, which would be incremented as the last command in your constructor. This way, if there was an `Exception` in the constructor, the counter would be intact.

```
public final class Car {
    private static AtomicLong carCounter = new AtomicLong();
    public Car() {
        //do the dirty things here
        carCounter.incrementAndGet();
    }  
    public static long getCounterValue() {
        return carCounter.get();
    }
}
```

I also would make the class `final`, because if a class extends this one, its constructor could perform operations after the counter was saved, and that would leave things in an inconsistent state (the counter wouldn't reflect the number of the created instances)...

With this much constraints, this is not a very useful situation, isn't it? I think the best solution would be using an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) to create the instances, and keep track of the counters. Maybe that abstract factory should even be a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)...